# Flutter, implement a method within a certain time

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

How can I implement a method within a certain time, if the time is out, cancel the method

for example,

if I have a method that may take 5 seconds to be implemented completely, and I want it to be implemented within 3 seconds, if that 3 seconds passed and the method not completed, then cancel it

is that possible?

Comment: ig You can use Timer, Stopwatch or [CancableOperation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html#:~:text=CancelableOperation%20class-,CancelableOperation%20class,successfully%20or%20with%20an%20error.)

Comment: check [Future.timeout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/timeout.html) - the docs say: "Stop waiting for this future after timeLimit has passed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible** to implement a mechanism to execute a method within a certain time frame and cancel it if it takes too long. Dart provides a Future class and the ***Future.timeout*** constructor, which allows you to set a timeout for a future operation.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  // Call the method with a timeout of 3 seconds
  executeMethodWithTimeout().then(
    (result) {
      print('Method completed successfully: $result');
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print('Method did not complete within the specified time: $error');
    },
  );
}

Future<String> longRunningMethod() async {
  // Simulate a long-running task
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

  // Return a result when the task is complete
  return 'Task completed successfully!';
}

Future<String> executeMethodWithTimeout() async {
  try {
    // Use Future.timeout to set a timeout of 3 seconds
    String result = await longRunningMethod().timeout(Duration(seconds: 3));
    return result;
  } on TimeoutException {
    // Handle the timeout
    throw 'Timeout: Method took longer than 3 seconds to complete';
  }
}
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?